# DensityPlot3D crashes GPU on Version 11(Mac Version)

Tags: bugs, crash, mac-os-x

First of all, I am using `"11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"` on Macbook Pro 2014 with non-switchable graphics.

I ran into this issue today when I try to evaluate this function DensityPlot3D. Whenever I type it in Front-End and trying to evaluate, the whole system crashes and screen freezes. Or even simpler, just type in the function name in the Documentation Center and the system will crash.

**WARNING, READ BEFORE YOU TRY:**  Not just Mathematica, but the whole operating system crashes. Be careful as you may lose all unsaved work if you try this!

---

I tried something before I edit this post/called wolfram earlier today:

1. I tried same function on Windows version of Mathematica, it works fine. However, I can reproduce this crash every-time I evaluate this function(any code has this particular function in it), or even by simply type it in documentation center.
2. I asked several of my friends(who owns a mac) on this issue, they report same issues as I experienced.
3. I also tried to reset Mathematica to its default configuration to see if helps, which not.

Now what I am wondering if anyone else on this site could reproduce the same thing...

Side note: I already called Wolfram and submitted a case about this issue to them.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it.  M11.0.1 on OS X 10.12.1, 2014 MacBook Pro with switchable graphics.

Comment: @Szabolcs mine was not switchable graphics

Comment: It would be better if you posted your hardware specs too, since this isn't happening on every machine.  Also post clear instructions on reproducing the crash. What are you evaluating?

Comment: @Szabolcs I just edited the post accordingly, since now I tend to believe this only happens to non switchable graphics Macbook... Also I can reproduce this crash even without evaluate anything: just type the function in the documentation center would crash the whole system. Or say, you can just copy any code has this function and run it will crash the system.

Comment: Yes, if I disable the NVIDIA graphics then it crashes.  I didn't read your post carefully. I thought only Mathematica would crash ...

Comment: Please don't remove the warning, others may get bitten too.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks, it's good to know other people are having issues so it's not my Macbook melting down...or want itself to be replaced...

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for the edit!

Comment: No crash for me in mma 11.0.1 with a two Nvidia switchable graphics cards macbook ... Seems definitely to concern only non nvidia cards ...

Comment: Can reproduce this error on M11.0.1 on macOS 10.12.1 on Macbook pro 2013 (late) with integrated graphics. Also, Image3D will kill the computer...